# Creating Object in Objective C iPhone SDK

Tags: javascript, objective-c, iphone

I need help creating an object for this declare

UIWebView *webView;

I  thought it was the object, but Its the declare in my header file. Can someone help me create the object for this declare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];`